# Trying to use a csv database to make a questionnaire with python

Tags: python, database, loops, csv, for-loop

I'm trying to create a database in python using a csv database, i have managed to get it working to the point where i can ask the user a question with multiple choices and depending on the users input a message displaying correct or incorrect will be printed. Now i am trying to tally up the correct and incorrect answers but am unable to get it working correctly. With the code i currently have the FOR statement at the bottom adds 1 and then never increments on it again. I have checked the type of correct_tally and it shows as int, i believe the code interprets my entire dataset as one piece of information but i dont understand why it doesnt output all the questions at once and instead shows each question individually and waits for an input... here is my code.

```
import csv

with open('questionnaire.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        question = row[3]
        option1 = row[4]
        option2 = row[5]
        option3 = row[6]
        option4 = row[7]
        prompt = "Which option do you pick? "
        answer = row[8]

        user_prompt = (f"" + question +"\n" + option1 + "\n" + option2 + "\n" +
                       option3 + "\n" + option4 + "\n" + prompt)

        questionnaire = input(user_prompt)

        correct = "Correct"
        incorrect = "Incorrect"

        correct_tally = 0

        for question in questionnaire:
            if questionnaire == answer:
                print(correct)
                correct_tally += 1
                print(correct_tally)
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inner loop is incorrect. There is no need to loop through the user response. Just loop through the csv file.

This update assumes the user gets only one attempt at a question.

```
import csv

correct = "Correct"
incorrect = "Incorrect"

correct_tally = 0

with open('questionnaire.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        question = row[3]
        option1 = row[4]
        option2 = row[5]
        option3 = row[6]
        option4 = row[7]
        prompt = "Which option do you pick? "
        answer = row[8]

        user_prompt = (f"" + question +"\n" + option1 + "\n" + option2 + "\n" +
                       option3 + "\n" + option4 + "\n" + prompt)

        reply = input(user_prompt)

        if reply == answer:
            print(correct)
            correct_tally += 1
            print('correct_tally',correct_tally)
        else:
            print(incorrect)
```